# Remote access to SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 (named instance) on a Windows Server 2012 R2:

1. Enabled remote access to SQL Server
2. Enabled shared memory & TCP/IP protocols & named pipes for the SQL Server instance.
3. Created a firewall rule for TCP Port 1433
4. Created a firewall rule for UDP Port 1434
5. Created a firewall rule for SQLBrowser.exe
6. Created a firewall rule for SQLservr.exe
7. Ensured SQL Browser & SQL Server are running

I'm able to remotely access SQL Server (ip\instance name,port number) but can't access with (ip\instance name).

I tried with turning off firewall, but the problem was not resolved.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What does "can't access" mean? Did you specify 1433 for the port number? Are you sure your named instance is running on that port? (That's not typical. I suspect you are connecting to the default instance when it succeeds, not your named instance.)

Comment: no, I am using dynamic port mode , actually i have only 1 SQL server(and that is named instance)

Comment: hi, error message is:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

Comment: and i use port number from TCP Dynamic ports field in IPALL tab on tcp/ip propertis, for example 49360

Comment: Sounds like if the port number works but no port doesn't, that SQL Browser is not, in fact, running. Did you search any of the [thousands and thousands of Google hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22network-related+or+instance-specific%22) or the [many existing questions already asked here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=Network-related+or+instance-specific)?

Comment: SQL Browser is running.

Comment: In "ip\instanceName" is "ip" the server name or it's IP address?

Comment: Also, have you tried restarting the instance and/or server?

Answer (score -2):

It is a known issue with Sql Server 2008. Happens also in SSAS.
Search for Microsoft fix/ or ask support for it (fix applies on the OS site and not the DB site).